# ethers.js version 6: TypeError: wallet.getTransactionCount is not a function

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js

I am getting the following error using ethers.js version 6 while getting the total transaction counts.

```bash
TypeError: wallet.getTransactionCount is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

in version 6 of ethers.js you should use getNonce() methoud

```
const nonce = await wallet.getNonce();
```

this is a link to the docs
[getNonce()](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/single-page/#Signer-getNonce)

Answer (score 0):

`getTransactionCount` is changed to `getNonce` in ethers.js version 6.

For ethers.js version 5;

```js
const nonce = await wallet.getTransactionCount()
```

For ethers.js version 6;

```js
const nonce = await wallet.getNonce()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ali's answer, `wallet` in this case is a [Signer](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Signer-getNonce).

From the docs, `getNonce`:

> Gets the next nonce required for this Signer to send a transaction.